# display loader gif whilst ajax request fetched

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

We have some code we use, that as the user types it fetches via ajax, the search results.

The issue I have is I don't want a submit button, we want the code to display a loader `gif` (ala FaceBook style pips) whilst the content is fetched. When there is success, hide the loader.

**Input Element:**

```
<input name="suburbs"  autocomplete="off" class="suburbsreviews" type="text" id="terms" size="50" onkeyup="getScriptPage('show_results','terms','1')" onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) this.value = this.defaultValue" onfocus="if ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) this.value = ''" <?if ($_GET['terms']){?>value="<?=$_GET['terms'];?>"<?}else{?>value="search"<?}?> />
```

I thought I would add a loading span that I can position in the input element absolutely using:

```
<span class="loader">Loading...</span>
```

Plus, I thought this code may work by displaying the loading pips:

```
$.loader({
onAjax: true,
align: 'center',
img: 'images/facebook/pip.gif',
mask: true
});
```

It isn't working. Any ideas why? I use the latest `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over complicating things, here's a function I use:

```
function setAreaTree(){
$('#projecthierarchy').html('<center><br><br><br><br><img src="img/loading_eeeeee.gif"></center>');
$.ajax({
    url: "sitemanager/sitemanager_ajax.php",
    data: {
        action:'getsidebar',
        pid:pid,
        aid:curaid,
        openareas:openareabars
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#projecthierarchy').html(data)
    }
}); 

}
```

So I just have a single div with id="projecthierarchy".  Immediately when the event is fired, the loader gif pops in, then when the ajax call returns successfully, it puts clobers that div with the content.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Not sure how we could implement that with our code, albeit looks like it should do what we want.. I am somewhat confuddled. Thanks anyway

Comment: well what is confusing? once the event happens, the loading gif pops in the div and spins or whatever. immediately after an ajax request is initiated, once it returns successfully, it puts the content in that div which wipes out what was there, namely the spinning gif.

Comment: For starters, I dont see why we need any of the code that you posted, your code may well fit your purposes. But our code fully works, we just need to initiate the loader. So a) dont need url, b) dont need data etc. The issue isnt to get the code to work, it fetches the data absolutely perfectly, and I dont see how we have over complicated it, in fact its really quite basic, and clean. All we want to do is fire the loader class, whilst data is being fetched.

Comment: well my function is about as vanilla as a jquery ajax call can be. your <input> element above is very very long and difficult to comprehend. it is generally advisable to separate your html and your javascript for readability sake.

Comment: will bear that in mind, oh well. Will do without the loader me thinks., cheers anyhoo